# Erro ao instalar mysqlclient no MacOs com python 3

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Erro ao instalar no macOs com python 3 pip3 install mysqlclient no MacOs

```
    iMac-de-Qcx:~ gabrielveigalima$ pip3 install mysqlclient
    Collecting mysqlclient
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File

 "/private/var/folders/x0/z58kw6cs25q5_wy25s0x3lr00000gp/T/pip-install-z47p2lop/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 18, in <module>
            metadata, options = get_config()
          File "/private/var/folders/x0/z58kw6cs25q5_wy25s0x3lr00000gp/T/pip-install-z47p2lop/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in get_config
            libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
          File "/private/var/folders/x0/z58kw6cs25q5_wy25s0x3lr00000gp/T/pip-install-z47p2lop/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 60, in <listcomp>
            libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
          File "/private/var/folders/x0/z58kw6cs25q5_wy25s0x3lr00000gp/T/pip-install-z47p2lop/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 13, in dequote
            raise Exception("Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?")
        Exception: Wrong MySQL configuration: maybe https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971 ?

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x0/z58kw6cs25q5_wy25s0x3lr00000gp/T/pip-install-z47p2lop/mysqlclient/
```

Comment: Chegou a acessar o link https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86971  que ele sugere?

Comment: Atualiza primeiro o pip: 
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3

Verifica se tem permissão de root
pip3 install --upgrade mysqlclient